# Filtering out duplicate values in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm using php and mysql. I'm having a problem with my piece of code. I want to remove duplicates and output the unique ones.

.php code

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo  $row['post_category'];
echo array_unique(explode(',', $var));
```

the table:

```
id(1) = post_category(CategoryA)
id(2) = post_category(CategoryB)
id(3) = post_category(CategoryC)
id(4) = post_category(CategoryA, CategoryB)
id(5) = post_category(CategoryB, CategoryC)
```

I'm about to create dynamic url links to every category

Comment: do you want to remove duplicate array values?

Comment: Yes sir. But it returns "CategoryACategoryBCategoryCCategoryA,CategoryBCategoryB,CategoryC value =/

Comment: Have you tried out array_unique() function?

Comment: i posted an answer that will remove duplicate values from your array.check it

Comment: @user3064038 edit your result to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT post_category FROM blog_posts";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $var[] = $row['post_category'];
}
print_r($var);
```

Comment: Works perfectly too. How can I make the output like "Category A Category B Category C" plainly? Without the "Array ( [0] =>" and so on

Comment: just implode the array like  implode(" ", $var);

Comment: That works well too! Thanks alot! Now I've separated them with spaces, how can I make it a link? like this one.. CategoryA = dev/index.php/category=a and so on..

Comment: Yeah sure, explode your category with space and make apart "Category" and "A" and use this to make link

Answer (score 2):

use `DISTINCT` in your select query.

`SELECT DISTINCT post_category FROM blog_posts;`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get distinct values from your mysql query than use `DISTINCT` keyword.

and if you want to remove duplicate values from your multidimensional array then:

`$type` is the multidimensional array.as `array-unique` wont work for multidimensional arrays.

```
$type = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $type)));
$type=array_values($type);
```

Comment: I used the DISTINCT. Works perfectly, but how about for the items with two categories? Like id(4) = CategoryA, CategoryB and so on

Comment: use explode for this case